# selenium получаю массив ссылок, разбираю с помощью цикла фор, и отправляю запрос на сайт, но на втором запросе выдает ошибку

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
array_links = []

driver.get('https://')
time.sleep(3)
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cover')
for i in links:
    array_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

for y in array_links:
    driver.get(y)
```

Я чисто по глупости написал данный код. Что я имею веду под глупостью ?

```
 for i in links:
    array_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Я разбираю массив и ложу в массив... и потом перебираю и отправлю запросы

```
for y in array_links:
    driver.get(y)
```

Но зато все работает. Проходит время я снова пишу подобный код, только более правильно(по крайней мере я так думал)

```
driver.get('https://')
time.sleep(3)
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cover')
for i in links:
    driver.get(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

И в итоге

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Stacktrace:
0   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109890598 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4404632
1   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109817fa3 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 3911587
2   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094c4e6a 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 425578
3   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094c8037 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 438327
4   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094c7ed7 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 437975
5   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094c8b00 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 441088
6   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109532c1f 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 875551
7   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x000000010951ada2 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 777634
8   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109531f79 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 872313
9   7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x000000010951abd3 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 777171
10  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094efced 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 601325
11  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001094f0e51 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 605777
12  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001098600ce 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4206798
13  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109864797 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4224919
14  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x000000010986ba4f 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4254287
15  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001098654da 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4228314
16  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x000000010983e23f 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4067903
17  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001098826a8 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4347560
18  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x0000000109882816 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4347926
19  7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver       0x00000001098978fe 7cd3422ea4a4d140_chromedriver + 4434174
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6c2c92eb _pthread_body + 126
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6c2cc249 _pthread_start + 66
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6c2c840d thread_start + 13
```

Короче говоря у меня 3 вопроса
1 Почему работает первый метод ?
2 Почему не работает 2 метод ?
3 Как правильно с этим работать (получения ссылок с сайта и дальнейшего перехода по ним) ?
Буду очень благодарен если хотя бы на один из данных вопросов ответите

Comment: Может вы их заколебали и они внедрили защиту? Судя по поведению драйвера вы пытаетесь получить элемент, который не доступен. А если это другой ресурс, то вам следует изучать основы парсинга, а конкретно виды защиты сайта от автоматических запросов.

Comment: Я бы согласился если бы в двух случаях был один и тот же результат, но это не так , а отличаются лишь тем что  в первом варианте я беру массив с ссылками виде данных селениума и ложу их в массив попутно преобразовывая их в полноценные ссылки, после разбираю массив и с каждым разборам отправляю запрос, и все получаеться, а в втором случае я беру массив ссылок в виде данных селениума и сразу прохожусь циклом, беру ссылку в виде данных селениума и преобразовываю ее в ссылку полноценную и отправляю запрос, и так весь цикл, только выходит сделать одни запрос а дальше ошибка

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт, который указан в примере.

Comment: Я уже нашел ответ, если интересно можете прочитать ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Первый метод работает, потому что вы ищете атрибут `href` на исходной странице.
2. Второй метод срабатывает один раз, пока вы находитесь на исходной странице, затем вы переходите на другую страницу `driver.get(y)`, у вас другой DOM, в котором, конечно, нет элементов исходной страницы. Вы пытаетесь найти атрибут `href` в ссылках links, которых нет здесь. Поэтому и вылетает ошибка

> Сообщение: устаревшая ссылка на элемент: элемент не прикреплен к документу страницы.
> Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

1. Используйте работающий первый метод.

Comment: Я понял !!! У меня было совершено другое понятие как работает код, но теперь я понял, большое спасибо